# Save entire form to file in php

Tags: php, html

I have a standard web page enclosed within a PHP form. Is there a way to save the entire contents of the form (HTML included) out as a it's own HTML file with the form answers included? The answers are either a drop-down selector or a standard text entry box.

I'd rather not have to generate a new HTML file with the responses if I can.

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing as such as `PHP` form. You mean `HTML` form inside `<?` `?>` or `<?php` `?>` ??

Comment: What do you mean with a "PHP form"?

Comment: Yes, I phrased it badly. I have a PHP page that has a form in it. The HTML is within the <?php ?> and has a submit button linked to a $_POST (or will be)

Comment: You use javascript to submit the form to a php page you created. Said php page will dump all `$_POST[]` data to the file you specify with `file_put_contents`. That's one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use javascript to capture the current html and responses of the form on submit, assign this code to a hidden form field and then submit the form. Having said that, I don't think this is a very reliable solution and also it really should'nt be so difficult to generate the same form with responses in php.